# if array element conditional inside for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a series of locations returning in an array in JavaScript that I'm plotting on a Google Map.

I'm trying to change the type of marker icon depending the value on one of the array elements like so

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map,
    if (locations[i][3] == "Yes") {
      console.log("yes")
    } else {
      console.log("no")
    }
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
```

but running into

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
```

What am I missing?

Comment: yeah, that does work but I should have been more specific: within the new google.maps.Marker({ I need to be able to set icon: '/img/a.png' or icon: '/img/b.png' depending on the value of locations[i][3]

Comment: you can use self executing function like so http://jsbin.com/tacoro/2/edit?js,output, or use ternary operator  http://jsbin.com/tacoro/3/edit?js,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I missing?

You're putting flow code in the middle of an object initializer:

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map,
    if (locations[i][3] == "Yes") {     // ====
      console.log("yes")                // ====
    } else {                            // ==== Here
      console.log("no")                 // ====
    }                                   // ====
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
```

You can't do that. <s>I'm not sure what you're trying to do there</s> You've posted a clarifying comment:

> within the new google.maps.Marker({ I need to be able to set icon: '/img/a.png' or icon: '/img/b.png' depending on the value of locations[i][3]

So my guess about a property was correct: You can do that with the conditional operator:

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
  map: map,
  icon: locations[i][3] == "Yes" ? '/img/a.png' : '/img/b.png'
});
```

...where the `icon` property's value will be `'/img/a.png'` if `locations[i][3] == "Yes"` is true, or `'/img/b.png'` if not.

Comment: I'm going to accept this on the basis of it being more succinct